# Why does 'I' take plural verbs?

Tags: grammatical-number

I cannot find the answer to this in the EL&U archives but I am sure it must be there somewhere and that this is a duplicate question.

Singular :

> He/she goes to the shops every day.

Plural :

> We/they go to the shops every day.

Why am I plural ?

> I go to the shops every day.

---

EDIT : The supposed duplicate is an interesting question and has a very competent answer but the answer is very broad and does not specifically answer my own question. People learning English often err in this very matter and it would be interesting if someone could answer more specifically to give an orderly reason why we do something in English that appears to be either completely chaotic or strangely contradictory.

Comment: If you look at the conjugations now, one way to analyze it that  it looks like the first person singular form of verbs is the same as 1st/2nd/3rd person plural forms. _Or_ you could just say that the 3rd person singular is just a weird exception. But if you look historically, you just realize that it is just that endings in most of the person/numbers dropped except for 3rd person singular. So it is coincidence.

Comment: "Why am I plural?" sounds a bit funny, who says there are more than one "I"? I know, the examples clarified. However, you could have made the question clearer, and less ambiguous. Oh, and added a bit of research, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The conjugation used to be (in Chaucer's Middle English) for the verb *heren* (meaning *hear*),

> I here, thou herest, he hereth, we/you/they heren.

So the plural form really used to be different. See [this website](https://user.phil.hhu.de/~kuehnert/mereader/5_3Middle_English_mn.html).

Over the centuries, the endings have changed. First, the "n" on the plural form was dropped. Then, people stopped pronouncing "e"s on the ends of words. And finally, the second person singular *thou* was lost. So the conjugation is now

> I hear, you hear, he hears, we/you/they hear.

So now, it looks like *I* and *you* take the plural form. And in fact, for all practical purposes, they do. But historically, *I hear* is a singular form that is no longer distinguishable from the plural form, and *you hear* is a plural form that has become singular.

Comment: Interesting. Thank you. (Up-voted and accepted as answer.)

Comment: (And at some point the 3sg ending _-(e)th_ was substituted for the rival ending _-(e)s_ across the board.)

Answer (score -1):

I had an immediate answer after reading the title of the question. I will answer that alone; I have no idea what the body of the question asks.

There is something called the Subjunctive Mood of verbs. An example is "If I were a rich man." The difference between that and "If I was a rich man" is the plural verb with singular subject acts as if to add 'but that is not really so' to the meaning.

You may wish to research it. There are not many situations where it can be shown - because for most tenses singular and plural verb are the same. You might never need to understand it: it's use is **always** optional.

Comment: The examples in the original post are not examples of the English subjunctive.

Comment: Frankly, I gave up on your examples when I saw: Why am I plural ? // I go to the shops every day. // 'I go' is the correct **singular** form.

Comment: I consider your down vote unjustified. The body of the question is incomprehensible. The question itself has some meaning. I explained what I was answering.

Comment: I am not the original poster. The question is asking why the singular and plural forms of the present tense indicative are the same. Do not assume that a community member who tries to be helpful by leaving a comment on a post has voted any which way on it.

Comment: I apologise for not using "whoever voted down" instead of "your vote down". // I don't think any native speaker should be faulted for failing the understand that OP.

Comment: There's one golden rule I always teach my Italian private students when they have to sit an English exam and write an essay. Answer the question asked, not the one you think was asked. Answering a question based only on its title does not make a good answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Am I being criticised for providing extra information beyond what was specifically asked by the question? I found the body of the question incomprehensible. Maybe there are better mind-readers than me here, but I could not come up with any plausible idea for what the OP may have wanted from their words. I explained what question I was answering - and why. What harm was I causing?

Comment: Then don't waste your intellect on answering a question that was incomprehensible to you in the first place. By the way, have you read Peter Shor's answer? It provides an explanation why verbs in English only inflects in 3rd person singular, which is what the OP was really after. P.S Not my downvote.

Comment: @Mari-LouA BTW, did you notice the comments I made yesterday to Edwin. I stated my opinions about various moderators here. They included my opinions (a) Edwin is a "polite gentle man", (b) you are a "nice person", and (c) others my opinions are not allowable here.

Comment: Yes, I did but I thought better to keep a distance. It's too easy to get drawn into arguments. :)

Comment: @Mari-LouA Basically, I'm fed up here - **NOT** with the rules, per se - but with their unequal enforcement. When I see FumbleFingers obeying the rules, or being criticised for not doing so in they same way I am - then I will happily learn and obey them. I do not expect that will happen. The site surely has policies for dealing with unrepentant recidivists. PLEASE, ensure my name is added to that list ASAP.

Comment: Frankly, the site reminds me of Monty Python-style skits about Victorian-era boarding schools for upper-class boys … the head prefect can do whatever he pleases and nobody says a word. Meanwhile, the other prefects are running around looking for any transgressions by lower-form boys - however minor, and in David's case inventing transgressions because he resented being told he missed the point of a question – for the pleasure of dishing out a damn-good thrashing to whatever unfortunate they catch.

Comment: Friendly reminder that comments should only be used to “[request clarification from the author; leave constructive criticism that guides the author in improving the post; \[or to\] add relevant but minor or transient information to a post (e.g. a link to a related question, or an alert to the author that the question has been updated)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment)”. This is not directed at anybody in particular. It is directed at the long trail of comments attached to this answer.

Comment: People who answer questions they don't understand really shouldn't be that surprised if they get downvoted. If you don't understand a question, leave a comment. Your answer here was harmless, so I'm not downvoting, but there are times when people don't understand a question and give an answer that is the complete opposite from the correct one.